# own domain in s3 vultr bucket

Tags: amazon-s3, object-storage, vultr

I have an S3 Vultr bucket, I'm using it to stream, but I want to use my own domain, like s3proxy.mydomain.com, instead of sjc1.vultrobjects.com/mybucket.

I want my domain (s3proxy.mydomain.com) to be recognized and proxy to the original domain, example:

I want to access the minicarro-ark-zero.jpg object. the original domain would be: https://sjc1.vultrobjects.com/bytebunker/minicarro-ark-zero.jpg, however I want to use my own domain and it would be: https://s3proxy.mydomain.com/minicarro-ark-zero .jpg

I've already done several configurations, including the simplest just adding a CNAME, others with nginx (scaleway example: https://www.scaleway.com/en/docs/tutorials/setup-nginx-reverse-proxy-s3/ #installing-nginx-as-a-reverse-proxy) or even an app using flask + boto3 (to connect to bcuket) and nginx, but nothing worked.

Does anyone have any idea what I can do to access the objects via my domain without passing the bucket in the url, whether the object is public or private, all in the vultr structure?

I expected to access my objects from my own domain to add to a strm file and stream, but there are always connection errors, or it connects but the connection always drops

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow  'nothing worked.' is super unclear. I recommend [taking the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), as well as reading [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [what's on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).